# WSO2 Identity Server User Registration validation using OTP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I need to implement user verification using email containing OTP(Randomly generated 4 digit number) for newly registered user accounts in WSO2 Identity Server but I could not find such functionality. Is there any feature in the repository that might help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can follows the https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+EmailOTP+Authenticator it describes the steps that you need to follow